# Convert a table with infrequent values for specific days to a table with all days in a period

Tags: mysql, sql

I got the following MySQL table storing a value to a specific date:

```
| date       | value |
======================
| 2009-03-29 | 0.5   |
| 2010-01-30 | 0.55  |
| 2011-08-12 | 0.67  |
```

Now I need another table that maps those values to every day in the range of the first and last date in the table (fill the gaps). So in the end it should look like this:

```
| date       | value |
======================
| 2009-03-29 | 0.5   |
| 2009-03-30 | 0.5   |
| 2009-04-01 | 0.5   |
| ...        | ...   |
| 2010-01-30 | 0.55  |
| 2010-02-01 | 0.55  |
| 2010-02-02 | 0.55  |
| ...        | ...   |
| 2011-08-10 | 0.55  |
| 2011-08-11 | 0.55  |
| 2011-08-12 | 0.67  |
```

Is there a way to solve this problem in a SQL query?

Comment: Do 2011-08-10 and 2011-08-11 have to be 0.67, not 0.55?
And - do you really need it in SQL? It would be way easier to do with a simple loop on an application layer.

Comment: you are right - thanks for the hint! I corrected it

Comment: Actually, why do you want to fill the table? Because maybe the problem you're trying to solve by filling the table can be solved with the table as is, without storing redundant information.

Comment: @Konerak: Yeah that would be nice too. I'm just not too confident with SQL unfortunately. What I need in the end is to join another table with the table above. So I need a way to get a table "A" with any date joined with the table "B" above having the values from the last date below the date of the table "A".

Comment: @Benjamin I think if you post your full use case, you'll be surprised how people will provide you a solution that may not require to have a table that you are asking for currently.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. This is the full case:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446444/join-two-tables-where-table-a-has-a-date-value-and-needs-to-find-the-next-date-i

Answer (score 1):

From the other case, and what you appear to be doing is to show the trend of values across some period of time, even though a value may not be provided every day... So, you may have from Oct 1, 2011 to Dec 1, 2011 (or any other date range for that matter).

You can easily SIMULATE an entire range of dates by using mysql variables and joining to ANY table (where I have "AnyOtherTableInYourDatabase") that has at least the number of days you would want to look back at.  In the example for just the dates, I am starting with whatever the current date is, and running back say... 60 days.  You could also change the "starting date" with something else and go back/forward as needed.

```
select  JustDates.OneDate
    from 
        ( SELECT 
                 @r:= date_add(@r, interval 1 day ) OneDate
            FROM 
                 (select @r := current_date()) vars,
                AnyOtherTableInYourDatabase limit 30 ) JustDates
```

Now, to get the most recent "reading", tack on a column via a select/from.  THEN, re-join THAT result set to the original readings table to get the value in question

```
select
      PreQuery.OneDate,
      PreQuery.LatestReading,
      Y2.Value
   from 
      ( select  JustDates.OneDate,
                ( select max( YRT.Date )
                     from YourReadingsTable YRT
                     where YRT.Date <= JustDates.OneDate ) as LatestReading
           from 
              (SELECT @r:= date_add(@r, interval 1 day ) OneDate
                  FROM (select @r := current_date()) vars,
                       AnyOtherTableInYourDatabase limit 30 ) JustDates ) PreQuery
      JOIN YourReadingsTable Y2
         on PreQuery.LatestReading = Y2.Date
```