# Join two tables where table A has a date value and needs to find the next date in B below the date in A

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I got this table "A":

```
| id | date       |
===================
| 1  | 2010-01-13 |
| 2  | 2011-04-19 |
| 3  | 2011-05-07 |
| .. | ...        |
```

and this table "B":

```
| date       | value |
======================
| 2009-03-29 | 0.5   |
| 2010-01-30 | 0.55  |
| 2011-08-12 | 0.67  |
```

Now I am looking for a way to JOIN those two tables having the "value" column in "B" mapped to the dates in "A". The tricky part for me here is that table "B" only stores the change date and the new value. Now when I need this value in table "A" the SQL needs to look back what date is the next below the date it is asking the value for.

So in the end the JOIN of those tables should look like this:

```
| id | date       | value |
===========================
| 1  | 2010-01-13 | 0.5   |
| 2  | 2011-04-19 | 0.55  |
| 3  | 2011-05-07 | 0.55  |
| .. | ...        | ...   |
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as how B relates to A - are you looking for the next date in B that is after a date in A (that would make the first row of the example 0.55 rather than 0.5)?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to join A and B using the ceiling date in B less than or equal to the date of A? Is that it?

Comment: no the date in B must be <= the one in A

Comment: @Benjamin: glad you asked like this - it will give better solutions than filling a sparse table where it was not really needed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-- Create and fill first table
CREATE TABLE `id_date` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `iddate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `id_date` VALUES(1, '2010-01-13');
INSERT INTO `id_date` VALUES(2, '2011-04-19');
INSERT INTO `id_date` VALUES(3, '2011-05-07');

-- Create and fill second table    
CREATE TABLE `date_val` (
  `mydate` date NOT NULL,
  `myval` varchar(4) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `date_val` VALUES('2009-03-29', '0.5');
INSERT INTO `date_val` VALUES('2010-01-30', '0.55');
INSERT INTO `date_val` VALUES('2011-08-12', '0.67');

-- Get the result table as asked in question
SELECT iddate, t2.mydate, t2.myval
FROM `id_date` t1
JOIN date_val t2 ON t2.mydate <= t1.iddate
AND t2.mydate = ( 
SELECT MAX( t3.mydate ) 
FROM `date_val` t3
WHERE t3.mydate <= t1.iddate )
```

What we're doing:

- for each date in the `id_date` table (your table `A`),
- we find the date in the `date_val` table (your table `B`)
- which is the highest date in the `date_val` table (but still smaller than the id_date.date)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery with `limit 1` to look up the latest value in table B:

```
select  id
,       date
,       (
        select  value
        from    B
        where   B.date < A.date
        order by
                B.date desc
        limit   1
        ) as value
from    A
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been inspired by the other answers but ended with my own solution using common table expressions:

```
WITH datecombination (id, adate, bdate) AS 
(
SELECT id, A.date, MAX(B.Date) as Bdate
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN tableB B
ON B.date <= A.date
GROUP BY A.id, A.date
)
SELECT DC.id, DC.adate, B.value FROM datecombination DC
LEFT JOIN tableB B
ON DC.bdate = B.bdate
```

Answer (score -1):

The INNER JOIN return rows when there is at least one match in both tables. Try this.

```
Select A.id,A.date,b.value 
from A inner join B 
on A.date=b.date
```

Comment: Your query will not work, they are looking for the _closest match_ to the date in table A. If you look at the dates none of them match table B but the expected output displays values for them.