# Join two tables on date, where date from right table is greater than date from left table but less than the next greatest date in right table

Tags: ms-access

MS-ACCESS question: We have are discharge dates and lookup dates. We need to have a lookup after each discharge. Problem is, of course, what happens when there are two discharges and two lookups, but where both lookups are after the second discharge, does one of the two lookups count toward the first discharge? Our policy is that no, it does not. In other words, **the lookup date only relates to a discharge date if the lookup was after the discharge date but before the next discharge date**.

My question seems similar to [Join two tables where table A has a date value and needs to find the next date in B below the date in A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446444/join-two-tables-where-table-a-has-a-date-value-and-needs-to-find-the-next-date-i) but that question is only looking for the next highest date, whereas my criteria are more involved.

I have two tables:
**tblDischarge** with a field DDate
DDate
7/1/2015
7/5/2015
7/20/2015

And **tblLookup** with a field LDate
LDate
7/2/2015
7/3/2015
7/23/2015
7/25/2015

Based on the rule, I need to get:
DDate | LDate
7/1/2015 | 7/2/2015
7/1/2015 | 7/3/2015
7/20/2015 | 7/23/2015
7/20/2015 | 7/25/2015

Notice that DDate of 7/5/2015 does not have a match because the lookups greater than 7/5/2015 were greater than the next highest DDate of 7/20/2015.

I have not gotten very far. I have:

SELECT tblDischarge.[DDate], [tblLookup].[LDate]
FROM tblDischarge INNER JOIN tblLookup ON ([tblLookup].[LDate]>tblDischarge.[DDate] AND ([tblLookup].[LDate]>MIN(tblDischarge.[DDate]>[tblLookup].[LDate]));

I am looking for the rest of the ON clause. I was using an IIF but I think that is more complicated than it needs to be. **I think I just need AND "something that compares LDate to the MIN of DDate > LDate". I have that bit after the AND currently, but it obviously sucks and is not working.**

Any ideas on how this might work?

---

**EDIT TO ADD** the full tables and what this really looks like:

tblDischarge

```
+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-------+
|   DDate   | D_FName | D_LName |   D_DOB    | D_Sex |
+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-------+
| 7/1/2015  | Joe     | Blow    | 12/12/2012 | M     |
| 7/5/2015  | Joe     | Blow    | 12/12/2012 | M     |
| 7/20/2015 | Joe     | Blow    | 12/12/2012 | M     |
| 7/3/2015  | Jane    | Doe     | 8/8/1974   | F     |
| 7/6/2015  | Jane    | Doe     | 8/8/1974   | F     |
| 7/15/2015 | Bill    | Nobody  | 5/5/1955   | M     |
| 7/12/2015 | Irene   | Dover   | 3/17/1942  | F     |
+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-------+
```

tblLookup

```
+------------------------------------------------------+  
¦   LDate   ¦ L_FName ¦ L_LName ¦   L_DOB    ¦ L_Sex   ¦  
¦-----------+---------+---------+------------+---------¦  
¦ 7/2/2015  ¦ Joe     ¦ Blow    ¦ 12/12/2012 ¦ M       ¦  
¦ 7/3/2015  ¦ Joe     ¦ Blow    ¦ 12/12/2012 ¦ M       ¦  
¦ 7/23/2015 ¦ Joe     ¦ Blow    ¦ 12/12/2012 ¦ M       ¦  
¦ 7/25/2015 ¦ Joe     ¦ Blow    ¦ 12/12/2012 ¦ M       ¦  
¦ 7/7/2015  ¦ Jane    ¦ Doe     ¦ 8/8/1974   ¦ F       ¦  
¦ 7/11/2015 ¦ Irene   ¦ Dover   ¦ 3/17/1942  ¦ F       ¦  
¦ 7/11/2015 ¦ Irene   ¦ Dover   ¦ 3/17/1942  ¦ F       ¦  
¦ 7/21/2015 ¦ Irene   ¦ Dover   ¦ 3/17/1942  ¦ F       ¦  
¦ 7/28/2015 ¦ Irene   ¦ Dover   ¦ 3/17/1942  ¦ F       ¦  
¦ 7/30/2015 ¦ Irene   ¦ Dover   ¦ 3/17/1942  ¦ F       ¦  
¦ 7/31/2015 ¦ Irene   ¦ Dover   ¦ 3/17/1942  ¦ F       ¦  
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried to edit the derived table to make the query look like this:

```
SELECT DerivedTable.DDate, DerivedTable.LDate, DerivedTable.D_FName, DerivedTable.D_LName, DerivedTable.D_DOB, DerivedTable.D_Sex, DerivedTable.NextDDate
FROM (SELECT tblDischarge.DDate, tblLookUp.LDate, Nz((SELECT TOP 1 t2.DDate FROM tblDischarge t2 WHERE t2.DDate > tblDischarge.DDate),DateAdd('d',30,tblDischarge.DDate)) AS NextDDate, tblDischarge.D_FName, tblDischarge.D_LName, tblDischarge.D_DOB, tblDischarge.D_Sex FROM tblDischarge INNER JOIN tblLookUp ON (tblDischarge.D_FName = tblLookUp.L_FName) AND (tblDischarge.D_LName = tblLookUp.L_LName) AND (tblDischarge.D_DOB = tblLookUp.L_DOB) AND (tblDischarge.D_Sex = tblLookUp.L_Sex) WHERE (((tblDischarge.DDate)<[tblLookUp].[LDate])))  AS DerivedTable
WHERE (((DerivedTable.LDate)<[NextDDate]));
```

But that is getting me the wrong NextDate.

What I am looking for is: for each person, which discharge dates have a lookup date later than the discharge date but not later than the next discharge date for the same person. The way I define person is by matching first, last, sex, and dob.

So in the sample data, Joe Blow's 7/1 and 7/20 discharges make the cut, but not the 7/5. For Jane Doe, only the the 7/6 discharge makes the cut, and for Irene, the 7/11 discharge makes it. And of course, Bill does not show up because he has no lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this multi-faceted approach using a subquery and derived table.

First, no joins need to be used. Simply start of with a cross join query that list tables in `FROM` clause returning all possible combinations of `DDate` and `LDate`. Then, filter the cross join of any records with `DDate < LDate`.

Then, use subquery to calculate `NextDDate`. Now, if there is no next date for very last record which would return `NULL`, use a `NZ()` to arbitrarily give it a top limit (here 30 days ahead). Finally a derived table is used to run one more `WHERE` clause to return where `LDate < NextDDate`:

```
SELECT DDate, LDate    
FROM
   (SELECT tblDischarge.DDate,    
           tblLookup.LDate,    
           Nz((SELECT TOP 1 t2.DDate FROM tblDischarge t2 
               WHERE t2.DDate > tblDischarge.DDate), 
             DateAdd('d', 30, tblDischarge.DDate)) As NextDDate    
    FROM tblDischarge, tblLookUp 
    WHERE tblDischarge.DDate < tblLookUp.LDate
) As DerivedTable    
WHERE LDate < NextDDate
```

OUTPUT (using your data as example):

```
DDate       LDate
7/1/2015    7/2/2015
7/1/2015    7/3/2015
7/20/2015   7/23/2015
7/20/2015   7/25/2015
```

**------EDIT------**

To incorporate detailed information (FName, LName, DOB, Sex) see updated queries:

*Derived Table* (can include in `FROM` clause or as external saved query). Here `INNER JOIN` is warranted with modification of nested subquery.

```
    SELECT tblDischarge.D_FName AS FName, tblDischarge.D_LName AS LName, 
           tblDischarge.D_DOB AS DOB, tblDischarge.D_Sex AS Sex, 
           tblDischarge.DDate, tblLookUp.LDate, 
           Nz((SELECT TOP 1 t2.DDate 
                 FROM tblDischarge t2 
                WHERE t2.DDate > tblDischarge.DDate 
                  AND t2.D_FName = tblDischarge.D_FName 
                  AND t2.D_LName = tblDischarge.D_LName),
              DateAdd('d',30,tblDischarge.DDate)) AS NextDDate
      FROM tblDischarge 
INNER JOIN tblLookUp ON (tblDischarge.D_FName = tblLookUp.L_FName)
       AND (tblDischarge.D_LName = tblLookUp.L_LName)
       AND (tblDischarge.D_DOB = tblLookUp.L_DOB) 
       AND  (tblDischarge.D_Sex = tblLookUp.L_Sex)
     WHERE (((tblDischarge.DDate) < [tblLookUp].[LDate]));
```

*Final Query*

```
SELECT FName, LName, DOB, Sex, DDate, LDate
FROM DerivedTable
WHERE LDate < NextDDate
ORDER BY LName, LDate;
```

*Output*

```
FName   LName   DOB        Sex  DDate       LDate
Joe     Blow    12/12/2012  M   7/1/2015    7/2/2015
Joe     Blow    12/12/2012  M   7/1/2015    7/3/2015
Joe     Blow    12/12/2012  M   7/20/2015   7/23/2015
Joe     Blow    12/12/2012  M   7/20/2015   7/25/2015
Jane    Doe     8/8/1974    F   7/6/2015    7/7/2015
Irene   Dover   3/17/1942   F   7/11/2015   7/21/2015
Irene   Dover   3/17/1942   F   7/11/2015   7/28/2015
Irene   Dover   3/17/1942   F   7/11/2015   7/30/2015
Irene   Dover   3/17/1942   F   7/11/2015   7/31/2015
```

Comment: Seems reasonable! Thanks for the Friday night answer. I'll test it out on Monday.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this does what I asked. The problem is that I was thinking that I could drop the solution into my bigger query but I can't. The tables I indicate actually have four fields each that I need to match on - FirstName, LastName, Sex, and DOB. What I actually need to do is what you've provided PLUS I need the name, sex, and DOB for each record to match. Should I ask a new question or perhaps edit this one?

Comment: Edit your post to include which fields go with which table plus how they join together (i.e., table structure) and I can modify the query to include those columns.

Comment: Are there no keys to relate the two tables? Also, can you apply the coding format to your post using the `{}` to be easier to read. You can also do so on the data output sections and align columns accordingly.

Comment: There are no keys. I guess I'm sort of improvising a key based on first, last, dob, and sex. I could concatenate those fields to make a key if necessary. I'll fix up the formatting.

Comment: we get the data from two sources. The unique identifiers for people are not consistent between the two so we use first, last, sex, dob as a proxy for a unique identifier.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks a million!